# Scrapy crawl http header data only

Tags: python, http-headers, scrapy

(How) can I archieve that scrapy only downloads the header data of a website (for check purposes etc.)

I've tried to disable some download-middlewares but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you asking about making "HEAD" requests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like @alexce said, you can issue HEAD [Request](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects)s instead of the default GET:

```
Request(url, method="HEAD")
```

<s>UPDATE: If you want to use HEAD requests for your `start_urls` you will need to override the make_requests_from_url method:</s>

```
def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
    return Request(url, method='HEAD', dont_filter=True)
```

UPDATE: `make_requests_from_url` was removed in Scrapy 2.6.

Comment: Thank you! But one further question: How do I set this setting in the initial class of the Spider? (Eg. class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider): start_urls = ... ) just writing method = "HEAD" here doesn't work

Comment: If you want to use HEAD requests for your start_urls you will need to override the `make_requests_from_url` method (answer updated).

Comment: The link to make_requests.. seems to be down :(