# Python: Getting all the URLs to a website that has a format

Tags: python, web-scraping

This may not be the right way to phrase this question, but is there a fast way to get the URLs of a website that has a format. What I mean by this is lets say the URL has a format of `www.example.com/stuff/number=0123456789` where the numbers at the end are always 10 digits long.

Right now I am using scrapy to go through each URL format from `0000000000` to `9999999999` which is 10 billion different combinations to see if there is a webpage located there. Although I am running multiple instances, and it is going pretty fast, it will still take forever and there has to be a better way to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a Python question really, it seems more like you're asking how you can know what URLs are published on a web site. The answer is that unless the site makes it known what the URLs are (they follow a pattern, they have a link to all pages, they publish a site map, etc.) there isn't. But there usually is and that's up to whomever wrote the web site.

Comment: But there is no better solution to try and brute force it? I was thinking about beautiful soup, but I think the 10 digits at the end passes through a JSP and points to locations on a server.

Comment: `Beautifulsoup` won't help unless you are trying to pull data from the HTML source. It won't help you identify if pages are available for `number=0123456789`. You can try speeding up the requests by doing a `HEAD` instead of a `GET` request.

Answer (score 1):

`Scrapy` itself is pretty fast, configurable and scalable. I would stick to it, try to optimize the current approach and scale it. For instance:

- use [`HEAD` requests](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) instead of `GET` (and see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982890/scrapy-crawl-http-header-data-only) also)
- [distribute the work](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#distributed-crawls) across multiple [`scrapyd` instances](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). You can also use libraries like [`scrapy-redis`](https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-redis) to keep the queue of urls to check and scraped items (if there are any)

But, be sure you are staying on the legal side and not violating the Terms of Use of the website.

---

As a side note and to resolve the confusion, `BeautifulSoup` is an HTML Parser and it is good at what it does. It cannot make HTTP requests itself. It needs an HTML to be passed into.

---

As an another side note, in general, it doesn't sound quite right to get all of the 10-digit combinations and check if there is a webpage corresponding to a number. If you would elaborate more about the motivation behind the problem, we can come up with more options or an alternative approach.